# DateTime.Today , beginning or end of the day?

Tags: c#, datetime

I am using `DateTime.Today`.

Now I'm not sure if the date is from the beginning of the day or the end of the day.

This is what `DateTime.Today` returns : `{11-3-2014 0:00:00}`

Comment: Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Looking back at this question today *Facepalm*

Comment: upvoted, I have some real gems in my past too haha. But on a serious note, the answer to your question helped me so its legit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MSDN states the following: "An object that is set to today's date, with the time component set to 00:00:00."

This means that a DateTime object is created with today's date at the absolute start of the day hence 00:00:00.

You can check if it is the start of the day by using the AddHour() method of the DateTime class.

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Today;
//AddHours, AddMinutes or AddSeconds
d = d.AddHours(1);
if (d.Date != DateTime.Today.Date) 
{ 
   //Not the same day
}
```

If d.date should be different the date was initialised at a different time (eg. 23:00:01).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MCollard:- Also to note that .Today always use the 00:00:00 part. If you want to get the time as well then use .Now! So you can say that .Today is essentially the same as .Now.Date Updated in my answer also! :)

Answer (score 8):

0:00:00 is the start of the day and 23:59:59 is the end of day.

You can also confirm through this **[24-hour clock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight)**

> **In the 24-hour time notation, the day begins at midnight, 00:00, and the last minute of the day begins at 23:59.** Where convenient, the
>   notation 24:00 may also be used to refer to midnight at the end of a
>   given date[5] – that is, 24:00 of one day is the same time as 00:00 of
>   the following day.

**On a side note:-**

If you want to know the time then use `.Now`  because that includes the 10:32:32 or whatever time; however `.Today` is the **date-part only** (at 00:00:00 on that day ie the begining of the day). So you can say that `.Today` is essentially the same as `.Now.Date`

Answer (score 6):

Thats the beginning of the day, the end of the day would be:

```
{11-3-2014 23:59:59}
```

And remember, the only stupid question is the one you don't ask :)

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime.Today` returns the current `DateTime` value, without the `Time` part.

Which means, it is the the first possible `DateTime` value for the current day.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like this:

The last moment in a day can be 23:59 or theoretically any amount of nanseconds before the next day. the next day then starts at 00:00:00 counting upwards.

So `11-3-2014 0:00:00` marks the beginning of a day. Either the earliest possible moment, or no time at all, if you want to treat 0:00:00 as a default value.